# Minimizing the number of event listeners to achieve a "Draggable" behaviour

Tags: javascript, event-listener

### Objective

Trying to replicate jQueryUI's [`.draggable`](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) behaviour.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".box").draggable();
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

---

### A *not some much* working solution

I have created a function `draggable` that does that. It takes in as argument an object of type `HTMLElement`: the element that needs to be draggable. The function need to follow these two points:

- the function can be called on multiple elements, so that more that one element on the page can be dragged (only one element can be dragged at the time like jQueryUI does it)
- the draggable elements can be dragged wherever the user wants it to move on the page (more precisely in the parent container).

I have started writing the function, it works as follows:

1. it adds an `onmousedown` event listener on the **element**

   when the event is triggered the distance (on `x` and `y`) from the mouse position to the corner of the dragged element is saved inside `relativeX` and `relativeY`. Also the state of `dragging` is changed from `false` to `true`.
2. it adds an `onmousemove` event listener on **`document`**

   The event keeps getting triggered when the user's mouse moves on the page. This allows to check if the state of `dragging` is `true`. When the state is indeed `true`, it means the user is dragging the element. Therefore the position of the element needs to be updated. I use the absolute positioning to get these positions right taking in account the relative positions (`relativeX` and `relativeY` saved earlier).
3. it adds both `onmouseleave` and `onmouseup` on **`document`** to end the behaviour when needed:

   when the user stops dragging the element (<kbd>LEFT Mouse Button</kbd> up) or leaves the `document` the function changes the state of `dragging` back to `false`. So the `onmousemove` listener will keep listening but won't update the position until `dragging` is set back to `true` again.

Here's the code to better illustrate:

```js
const relativePos = (e, p) => {
  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  return [e.clientX - rect.x, e.clientY - rect.y];
}

const draggable = draggedE => {

  let isDragging, relativeX, relativeY;

  // checking if the user is dragging
  document.onmousemove = (event) => {
    if (isDragging) {
      draggedE.style.left = `${event.clientX - relativeX}px`
      draggedE.style.top = `${event.clientY - relativeY}px`
    }
  }

  // when the user initiate the dragging behaviour
  draggedE.onmousedown = e => {
    [isDragging, relativeX, relativeY] = [true, ...relativePos(e)]
  }

  // listener to end the behaviour 
  document.onmouseup = () => isDragging = false
  document.onmouseleave = () => isDragging = false
  
}

draggable(document.querySelector('.box'))
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

### Problems with the event listeners

The code works perfectly. **But here are my concerns**:

I am using lots of draggable elements. For each one of them there is an event attached to the document to check for the state of `dragging`. This doesn't seem very good for performance.

Also if you look closely at the animation below (using jQueryUI's [`.draggable`](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) method):

[image]

You can see I'm able to get out of the page without the behaviour getting stopped: I can drag elements outside of the page. I found that I can only achieve such result by attaching my listeners to the **`document`**. Attaching it to the parent element or even the `body` won't work.

---

### My question

**How can I achieve the result described above without using that many event handlers (on the parent and worse on `document`) while still ensuring the same behaviour?**

---

### [EDIT] Possible solution

[Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) suggested that:

- I create an object `draggable` containing all methods
- Add a unique `mousedown` event handler on `document`

Here's how it looks like:

```js
const draggable = {
  startDrag: function(event) {
    this.element = event.target
    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.offset = [event.clientX - rect.x, event.clientY - rect.y];
  },
  dragging: function(e) {
    this.element.style.left = `${e.clientX - this.offset[0]}px`;
    this.element.style.top = `${e.clientY - this.offset[1]}px`;
  },
  endDrag: function() {},
  element: '',
  offset: []
};

document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {

  if (e.target.classList.contains('draggable')) {

    draggable.startDrag(e)

    const _mousemove = draggable.dragging.bind(draggable)
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', _mousemove);

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function _mouseup(event) {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', _mousemove)
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', _mouseup)
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightblue;
  top: 125px;
  left: 125px;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightgreen;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable box"></div>
<div class="draggable box"></div>
<div class="draggable box"></div>
```

Having to name the functions used by the handlers in order to later delete them troubles me. **Is there no other way of going about deleting the events without necessarely calling `bind`?**

Comment: At first, add an identifier to draggable elements (class or data-* attribute). Create an object containing move and endMove methods and draggableElement property. Then add a single mousedown listener to `document`, and in the handler, recognize a draggable and assign a reference to draggableElement, attach mousemove and mouseup listeners to document. In mouseup handler simply remove the listeners attached in mousedown.

Comment: Thank you @Teemu, I have edited my post with the new code. Is this ok? Also is there a wya to avoid this line: `const _mousemove = draggable.dragging.bind(draggable)`?

Comment: That's a nice snippet of code. Binding should be OK here. Only the use of `data` is bit off. Use [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead of a custom attribute, e.g. `data-draggable="1"` or something similar. A class would do as well, ofcourse.

Comment: You're right it isn't needed here. I have updated the code by checking if the element has the class name `draggable`.

Comment: There's the empty function `endDrag` in the object. In my comment that was puprposed to be the document.mouseup handler, but as you've applied the idea works as well, and the extra empty function is not needed.

Comment: Were you thinking of having `const _mouseup = draggable.endDrag.bind(draggable); document.addEventListener('mouseup', _mouseup);` instead and have the "removeEvent" statements in `.endDrag`?

Comment: Yup, attaching listeners to exisiting functions is faster than creating a new function for every listener. Not that it would be a bottleneck here ... Anyway, this way you have only a single listener in the queue all the time, and only few temporary listeners, no matter how many draggables you need in the document.

Comment: @Teemu I have added an answer with some more modifications: now I am saving the bound functions `_mousemove` and `_mouseup` inside `draggable` instead of having them as separate const variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) I have found a solution to my problem. The idea is to run a unique event listener when the user not dragging. When he does drag an element, other event listeners will be added **and removed as soon as the user ends the dragging process** either with `mouseup` or `mouseleave`.

`draggable` is an object containing all functions: `startDrag`, `dragging` and  `endDrag` and information: `element` and `offset` regarding the dragging mechanism.

In order to remove the event listeners, I needed to save my event functions in variables.

Furthermore, I had to use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) in order to have access to `draggable`'s properties inside the different functions. So I came up with the property `events` which is filled with `draggable`'s functions bound to `draggable`...

So I came up with:

```
(function() {
    this.events = {
      _mousemove: this.dragging.bind(this),
      _mouseup: this.endDrag.bind(this)
    }
}.bind(draggable))()
```

Instead of writing:

```
const _mousemove = draggable.dragging.bind(draggable)
const _mouseup = draggable.endDrag.bind(draggable)
```

So now I can stop the events linked to `_mousemove` and `_mouseup` inside `endDrag` by accessing them with `this.events._mousemove` and `this.events._mouseup`.

Now the event listeners can be added with:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draggable.events._mousemove);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', draggable.events._mouseup);
```

Here is the full JavaScript code:

```js
const draggable = {
  events: {},
  startDrag: function(event) {
    this.element = event.target
    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.offset = [event.clientX - rect.x, event.clientY - rect.y];
  },
  dragging: function(e) {
    this.element.style.left = `${e.clientX - this.offset[0]}px`;
    this.element.style.top = `${e.clientY - this.offset[1]}px`;
  },
  endDrag: function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.events._mousemove)
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.events._mouseup)
  },
  element: '',
  offset: []
};

document.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {

  (function() {
    this.events = {
      _mousemove: this.dragging.bind(this),
      _mouseup: this.endDrag.bind(this)
    }
  }.bind(draggable))()


  if (e.target.classList.contains('draggable')) {

    draggable.startDrag(e)

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', draggable.events._mousemove);

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', draggable.events._mouseup);

  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  user-select: none;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: lightblue;
  top: 125px;
  left: 125px;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightgreen;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="draggable box"></div>
<div class="draggable box"></div>
<div class="draggable box"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, maybe I could just have `dragging` and `endDrag` already bound to `draggable`, is this possible?

Comment: Looks like this has almost become a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ = ). There you'll meet real experts to optimize code, coding style etc.

Comment: You're wellcome. [This way](https://jsfiddle.net/2sL5w74t/) you can attach listeners without extranous binding. I'm bad with ES6, maybe this could be done with a class too.